# Get Data in edit_customer.blade.php file

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am using Laravel 8 for my project.

In edit_customer.blade.php I need to show individual data.

IN the Controller file I have used the following code:

```
function showCustData($cust_id ){

    $get_cust_data = AddCustomer::where('customer_id', $cust_id)->get();
    
    return view('edit_customer',['currentcustomer'=>$get_cust_data]);   
    }
```

and in the view file, I am getting the following result by using {{$currentcustomer}}:

```
[
  {
    "customer_id": 1,
    "current_admin_id": 0,
    "customer_type": "customer_type_purchase",
    "customer_name": "Sadhan Basu",
    "customer_gst": "12345789GST",
    "customer_account_number": "Ac1234567/89",
    "customer_stat_ut": "234234234",
    "customer_currency": "INR - Indian rupee",
    "customer_phone": "9874561230",
    "customer_email": "abc@test.com",
    "customer_country": "countryname",
    "customer_state": "ggg",
    "customer_city": "oooo",
    "customer_address": "Some Address here",
    "customer_proser": "product sold",
    "customer_product_hsn": "ad@dsg.fwe",
    "customer_product_sac": "fwsff",
    "reg_date": "2021-03-20 18:32:08"
  }
]
```

How to get these data individually?

I have tried following codes but getting error like those fields are missing:

```
1> {{$currentcustomer["customer_id"]}}
2> {{$currentcustomer->customer_id}}
```

Comment: The method `get()` returns you an array. If you want to access a single customer use `first()`.

Without changing method, you should be able access the customer_id with `{{ $currentcustomer[0]->customer_id}}`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You want to show individual data, It's very easy to retrieve data from database using `first()` method. You may use this method in your `controller` `showCustData()` method.

**Controller** method

```
function showCustData($cust_id ) {
    $currentcustomer = AddCustomer::where('customer_id', $cust_id)->first();
    return view('edit_customer', compact('currentcustomer'));   
}
```

**Blade** view

```
{{ $currentcustomer->customer_id }}
```

Comment: I have tried that code and it gives me the following error: Attempt to read property "customer_id" on string (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\saledoc\resources\views\edit_customer.blade.php)

Comment: Update my answer. Check it.

Comment: it shows the following error: Undefined variable $currentcustomer (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\saledoc\resources\views\edit_customer.blade.php)       
$currentcustomer is undefined

Comment: check with `dd($currentcustomer)`

Comment: It's getting error but upvote. This is really unfair

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like this

```
function showCustData($cust_id ){

    $get_cust_data = AddCustomer::where('customer_id', $cust_id)->first();

    return view('edit_customer',compact('get_cust_data'));   
}
```

And in your view file just use like this

```
{{ $get_cust_data->customer_id }} or {{ $get_cust_data->customer_type }} or ...
```

Comment: @knath632, If it works please accept and help of the other developer who will facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Just Use @foreach in The View and You Will Be Able To Access Your Array Object

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
<p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
```

@endforeach

and you could review the laravel documentation
[laravel blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade)